# Why is Firefox throwing off div width?

Tags: html, css, firefox

See this page: http://www.blakearchive.org/blake/public/exhibits/test.html

In Safari and Chrome the text is where it's supposed to be, but in Firefox it's not. The width of the text div is 34%, while the width of the gallery div is 66%. In Firefox, I have to set the width of the text div to 30% to get it to fall into the left hand column.

What can I do to fix this? Is there something unique to Firefox that's causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you put your code on here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

To your column and galleria elements. Mozilla doesn't use the generic `box-sizing` and needs it's own identifier `-moz-box-sizing`.

Comment: However, the text goes beyond the container in Firefox also. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: just directing my comment to you here

Comment: @user2697528, I'm not seeing any problems for the misalignment in Firefox when using my fix, could you post a screenshot and tell me what FF version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why it was happening like that in Firefox. I've put a fix in for now:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
        $('#contents').css("width", '30%');
        $('#right').css("width", '30%');
}
```

But this seems like a hack.

The other issue is that Firefox is not picking up the padding at the bottom of the text column. Ridiculous.